# Is it necessary to do git add "filename" to commit when working with cloning or it manually gets added right after adding the file into the vscode?

Tags: git, clone, commit, init

While starting with **git init** I added a file named **index.html** and currently it's on untrackable state so I did **git add index.html** to send it to stagging state. Further I committed it and it's done. But the same thing is not working while doing cloning. Is it necessary?

````
    git add index.html
    git status
    git commit```
````

Comment: `git clone` is effectively `git init`, `git add remote origin <url>`, and `git remote update origin` all in one.

Comment: @chepner presumably you mean `git remote add origin <url>` and not `git add remote ...`

Comment: I'd like to say I have an extensive alias system set up to do what I mean, not what I say, but ... yeah, that's a  typo.

Comment: @chepner I was not familiar with `git remote update`. Testing it just now, it  seems to do exactly the same thing as `git fetch`. And reading the manual, I honestly can't see how it's different...

Comment: And one more thing, your description of what git clone does is missing checking out the default branch and setting up its remote version as upstream.

Comment: `git remote update` is sort of a bulk `git fetch` for all (configured) branches.

Answer (score 1):

`git add` is used to add new files to a repo that aren't already there, or to add modifications to existing files. After a clone, you've got all the files already in the repo as it stands. You only need to `git add` new files or changes to existing files.